# how to update item app type using API php

Tags: php, api, podio

I'm writing a PHP script that is called from Globiflow to update items on my Inventory app. I have a item "app type", and I can't update with PodioItem::update, it send me a message error: PodioBadRequestError , the same script update another items "text type", without problem.
Here is part of my PHP code:

```
             $updItem = array("fields"=>array(
                "text" => $latitude,
                "text-2" => $longitude,
                "item-description" => "Location Updated by New KIA ",
                "action-by" => $lastAction,
                "last-action-by" => 'test@aol.com',
                ));
            
              PodioItem::update($inventario, $updItem);
```

The "last-action-b" field, is the one defined as a "app type".
Any ideas?, in advanced thank you for you help.

Answer (score 0):

Yous should pass the `item_id` of the corresponding item ('test@aol.com') from the referenced app in an array.

```
...
"last-action-by" => array(123456789),//123456789 is the item_id of 'test@aol.com'
...
```

Comment: Hi Muhammad,, thank you for your response.  I tried this way, but does not work:   $updLink = array("fields"=>array(
   "text" => $longitude,
   "text-2" => $latitude,
   "last-action-by" => array(1234567 => 'test@aol.com ),
         ));

Comment: Not like this, I assume there is an item having email field value as `test@aol.com` and you need to set that item in this field. So you need to take that item_id and provide here in an array, array(123456789); that's all.